# zsh bullet-train node version

Tags: nodejs, zsh, npm

Using zsh with the bullet-train theme. Messed around with Webstorm, trying to learn some basic react and didn't pay much attention to the cli prompt.

Now I see there's this trailing `v10.19.0`, which is the same as the output from `node --version`.

What does it stand for and how/why can I make it go away? Intuition would tell me that the shelll is now in some sort of virtualenv of the project I worked on.

[image: prompts]

Comment: Using some npm plugin? Are you also using oh-my-zsh or similar zsh frameworks?

Comment: yes, using oh-my-zsh as well.

Answer (score 0):

After having had the same issue, one solution i found was to add below prompt order and comment out `nvm` using `#` as described here [github comment](https://github.com/caiogondim/bullet-train.zsh/issues/208#issuecomment-300538873)

```
BULLETTRAIN_PROMPT_ORDER=(
time
status
custom
context
dir
#perl
ruby
virtualenv
#nvm
#aws
#go
#elixir
git
#hg
cmd_exec_time
)
```